# How to compare json data structures? Order and specific values matter

Tags: python, r

I have 10,000 query execution plan outputs as json and I am interested in comparing their overall structures, for example nested and data join type.

For example, I have these two json outputs:

Plan A:

```
[
  {
"Plan": {
  "Node Type": "Aggregate",
  "Strategy": "Sorted",
  "Startup Cost": 73683.11,
  "Total Cost": 73685.75,
  "Plan Rows": 66,
  "Plan Width": 124,
  "Group Key": ["(date_part('year'::text, (orders.o_orderdate)::timestamp without time zone))"],
  "Plans": [
    {
      "Node Type": "Sort",
      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
      "Startup Cost": 73683.11,
      "Total Cost": 73683.28,
      "Plan Rows": 66,
      "Plan Width": 124,
      "Sort Key": ["(date_part('year'::text, (orders.o_orderdate)::timestamp without time zone))"],
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Hash Join",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Join Type": "Inner",
          "Startup Cost": 468.21,
          "Total Cost": 73681.12,
          "Plan Rows": 66,
          "Plan Width": 124,
          "Hash Cond": "(supplier.s_nationkey = n2.n_nationkey)"}
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Plan B:

```
[
  {
"Plan": {
  "Node Type": "Aggregate",
  "Strategy": "Sorted",
  "Startup Cost": 87791.78,
  "Total Cost": 87796.62,
  "Plan Rows": 121,
  "Plan Width": 124,
  "Group Key": ["(date_part('year'::text, (orders.o_orderdate)::timestamp without time zone))"],
  "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Join Type": "Inner",
              "Startup Cost": 15344.96,
              "Total Cost": 87783.76,
              "Plan Rows": 121,
              "Plan Width": 24,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Hash Join",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Join Type": "Inner",
                  "Startup Cost": 15344.68,
                  "Total Cost": 87707.77,
                  "Plan Rows": 241,
                  "Plan Width": 24,
                  "Hash Cond": "(lineitem.l_partkey = part.p_partkey)"} 
                   ]
                }
              ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am only interested in comparing `Node Type` and `Parent Relationship`. The ultimate goal is to output a file that contains labels for distinct plans. I anticipate that out of the 10,000 query evaluation plans, there are probably fewer than 100 distinct plans and would like to label them as Plan 1, ..., Plan 100.

Edited to include: I have referred to https://www.haykranen.nl/2016/02/13/handling-complex-nested-dicts-in-python/
Tried `data.tree` in `R`.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd recommend starting small, try to compare two simple jsons/dicts first.

Comment: I am not sure how to extract *all* of the `node type` and `parent relationship` from the nested structure. So far, I am only able to return the first `node type`, which is `Sort` from Plan A.